# "Computer admin" vs active account?

Tags: user-account, login

So someone stole my mac and I just got a new used one and am setting it up and I can't figure out how to get it back to the way I used to have it.

The way it was before, I was a user with no password-- I didn't have to login when the mac started. But whenever I wanted to make significant changes, like installations or settings adjustments, I would have to give credentials.

How do I get back to that? Is it simply a matter of having a normal account and an admin account, and only using the normal account for day-to-day things? I never deliberately made two separate accounts on the previous computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to have one user who is an Admin and has a password.

In **System Preferences** navigate to **Users & Groups**.

- Ensure you only have one active user.
- Ensure that user has a password.

> **Note**: You might need to click the **Lock** button to make changes.

[image: users and groups]

Then click **Back** in **System Preferences**. Navigate to **Security & Privacy**. Click the **Lock** button to make changes. **Uncheck** all three checkboxes:

[image: security and privacy]

Now you will be able to turn on the computer without logging in. OS X will launch directly to the desktop. If you need to perform a Administrator level operation like using `sudo` in Terminal, you will be prompted for the password. Magic! :)